# WP Query Meta Query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I need to select posts to display based on two custom fields with a specific key and order them by a third.  THis is what I have, but it is not ordering correctly.

```
    <?php
$args           = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'Date Ordering Format',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'Event Type',
            'value' => '4. take-out tuesday',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'Past Event',
            'value' => 'Past',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
$featured_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($featured_query->have_posts()):
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()):
        $featured_query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="fullWidthSeason">';
        echo '<div class="pastEventImage">';
        if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')):
            MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'series-image', $post->ID, 'full', NULL, FALSE);
        endif;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="featuredBlockDate ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event Text Left or Right', true) . ' ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Black Text', true) . ' ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Black Text', true) . '">';
        echo 'Past Event: ';
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event Date', true);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="featuredBlockTitle  ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event Text Left or Right', true) . ' ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Black Text', true) . '">';
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Season Page Title', true);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="featuredBlockExcerpt  ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event Text Left or Right', true) . ' ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Black Text', true) . '">';
        echo the_excerpt();
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="moreButton  ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event Text Left or Right', true) . '">';
        echo '<div class="moreButtonSeason  ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event Text Left or Right', true) . '"><a href="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event RSVP Link', true) . '" target="_blank">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Event RSVP Link Text', true) . '</a></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Can you indent your code? It's very difficult to parse. It even looks like a part of the array at the beginning has been mixed up but it's hidden because the indenting is broken

Answer (score 0):

I think the orderby key is at the wrong place. It think it should be like this:

```
$args           = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'your key to order',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'Date Ordering Format',
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'Event Type',
            'value' => '4. take-out tuesday',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'Past Event',
            'value' => 'Past',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't filter correctly, it is outputting all post type 'event' that are not 'Past'.  It is not considering the 'Event Type'.